# PHP Paypal Verification

Tags: php, paypal

So I'm new working with paypal, the problem I have is that I don't really know where to start, this is what I have to do: My client wants to give lessons, so he customers will order lessons, and they have to specify a date and a time, and if it's available he can make the payment, what is the easiest way to do it?
Assuming the customer is logged in, all I need to do is once the payment has been sent accomodate the lesson into the database, can I do that with just paypal "Pay Now" buttons? Or do I need other library?
All I know is that paypal "Pay Now" button can redirect you to a "success" url but that's it.
What should I use for this? Is there a library or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go through this documentation to make your life easier !

[PHP PayPal API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks)

Comment: Looks like the WPS toolkit will do :)

Comment: Oh yes. If you got doubts come back and start a new topic., SO will help you out !. Best of luck.